# Semantic Role Labeler used in Java/vb.net

Tags: nlp

I want to use [Semantic Role Labeler](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/SRL) tool from Illinois in my project.

I've seen the online demo of the SRL tool. To use that tool, the website suggests downloading the Curator. I have downloaded this Curator file. But how do I use the Curator file in Java code or VB.NET code? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

And I also want to mention a few tips about Curator. The reason that you will need a Curator is that the SRL package as a complicated software now need a few external dependencies, for example, illinois Part of Speech, Shallow parsing, and currently Charniak parser. And Curator is a tool we used to manage those dependencies.

However, the curator will also installed a few other dependency that you may not need for SRL, for example, Named entity tagger, and Wikifier. Those component tends to consume plenty of RAM (for example, the two listed here will need 10GB), so you may want to turn them oof, by comment out the line in `$CURATOR_HOME/dist/startServer.sh` which should be self-explained.

Once you have Curator up and running, you can call it from you program using a curator-client package, the easiest way to do this in JAVA is using maven:

First add the CCG maven repo to your project:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>CogcompSoftware</id>
        <name>CogcompSoftware</name>
        <url>http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/m2repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then add the following dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-interfaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
     </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since the API and data structure are defined in Thrift, so you may use them in other language by generating the curator package via thrift, (However, VB.NET is not supported by Thrift as Daniel pointed out :) ) Watch for the CCG website if you are interested, we are writing a tutorial about how to do this, which should be public available very soon.

And after you have the above dependency, you should be able to follow our walkthrough on 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/curator/CuratorDemo.html

Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking several questions.

The standalone SRL is under development and it will be release soon.

The best way to access to SRL is currently installing Curator, which is explained here: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/trac/curator.php

I don't think you can use Curator in VB.Net. Since it is designed to the languages supposed by Apache Thrift : 
http://thrift.apache.org/about

After installing it you can easily access it in Java. Here is a Walkthrough: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/curator/CuratorDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use SENNA which is a free NLP tools  developed in ASNI c and could be run in visual studion.net
http://ronan.collobert.com/senna/
it can outputs: part-of-speech (POS) tags, chunking (CHK), name entity recognition (NER), semantic role labeling (SRL) and syntactic parsing (PSG).